# Problema con while fetch_assocc y string

Tags: php, html, sql

Lo que intento es obtener datos de la base de datos para crear etiquetas HTML del tipo `option` pero el problema es que lo que necesito mandar es un `string` y no un `array`.

El JavaScript que manda la información entre el HTML y PHP funciona bien si se le da el `string`.

Lo que necesito es combinar el `array` con el `string` y mandar un `string`. He intentado el método `implode` pero no me funciona. El problema seguramente se encuentra en el ciclo `while`.

```
<?php
require('lib.php');

$columna=$_POST['columna'];
$con = new ConectorBD();
$data = " ";
//Intenta la coneccion con la base de datos
if ($con->initConexion('base_de_datos')=='OK') {
//Hace la sentencia sql para consultar de forma correcta
$resultado = $con->consultar([$columna.'_tbl'],[$columna,'id'],'ORDER BY '.$columna.' ASC');

while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
   $data=$data.'<option value="'.$fila['id'].'">'.$fila[$columna].'</option>';
 }

}
$con->cerrarConexion();
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Esto es lo que hay en lib.php (crea sentencias sql correctamente)

```
<?php
class ConectorBD{

function consultar($tablas, $campos, $condicion = ""){
 $sql = "SELECT ";
 $ultima_key = end(array_keys($campos));
 foreach ($campos as $key => $value) {
   $sql .= $value;
   if ($key!=$ultima_key) {
    $sql.=", ";
  }else $sql .=" FROM ";
 }

$ultima_key = end(array_keys($tablas));
foreach ($tablas as $key => $value) {
  $sql .= $value;
  if ($key!=$ultima_key) {
    $sql.=", ";
  }else $sql .= " ";
}

 if ($condicion == "") {
   $sql .= ";";
 }else {
   $sql .= $condicion.";";
 }

 return $this->ejecutarQuery($sql);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: No entendi. Como veo que usas JSON, entiendes que JSON es un formato, cierto? Es la forma de representar algo. Todo lo que mandes de JavaScript a PHP y viceversa es un "string" pero si lo mandas en cierto formato (JSON), y con este formato podrias incluir un arreglo que tiene un arreglo dentro y un string dentro tambien, y por supuesto "del otro lado" se puede entender en cierta forma y transformalo en objeto/array/etc. Dicho esto, de donde a donde tienes tu problema? De PHP a JavaScript o viceversa? Esa es la parte que no entiendo.

Comment: Sería interesante que digas si un `print_r($resultado);` antes del `while` muestra algo en pantalla. Y... aunque no es (quizás) el problema, tu función `consultar` mantiene un código vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, el cual podría ser más facil y más seguro si implementas consultas preparadas con marcadores de posición (`?`).

Comment: Independientemente de la inyección sql que ya te han comentado, ¿qué es lo que quieres retornar exactamente? ¿Un String en json o solo un String o un Array en json? Pon en ejemplo de que resultado pretendes devolver.